# AngularJs Typeahead directive not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a simple requirement wherein a list of users is displayed and display a search button on top to search for the users by name, something like a simplified LinkedIn Connections page.

My web app is developed on node.js but this one page has been developed on angular.js and for this search button, I have decided to use the typeahead directive. This is how the jade file looks like:

```
html(ng-app='geniuses')
  head
    title List All Geniuses!
    link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js')
    script(src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js")
    script(src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.2/angularfire.min.js")
    script(src='js/listAllgeniuses.js')
  body
    div.container
      div.page-header
       h2 All Geniuses!
        div(ng-app='geniuses',ng-controller='SearchAGenius')
         input.form-control(placeholder='Genius',name='search-genius',ng-model="selected",typeahead="user for user in usersArr | filter:{'geniusid':$viewValue} | limitTo:8")
       div(ng-app='geniuses',ng-controller='GetAllGeniuses')
         ul
           li(ng-repeat='user in users') {{ user.geniusid }}
```

The list of users are being fetched as an array from firebase. As you can see, the list of users is fetched using GetAllGeniuses controller and it works fine.. Here is the controller code:

```
(function (angular) {
var app = angular.module('geniuses', ["firebase"]);

app.controller('GetAllGeniuses',  ["$scope", "$rootScope","$firebaseArray",
    function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseArray) {
      var users = $firebaseArray(new Firebase("****));
      $rootScope.usersArr = users;
      $scope.users = users;
}
])

app.controller('SearchAGenius',  ["$scope", "$rootScope",
    function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.selected = '';
      $scope.usersArr = $rootScope.usersArr;
}
])

}(angular));
```

This is how the data looks like(dummy):

```
[
{
geniusid: "new",
geniusname: ""
},
{
geniusid: "new",
geniusname: ""
},
{
geniusid: "news",
geniusname: ""
},
{
geniusid: "qazwsx",
geniusname: ""
}
]
```

I want to search using the geniusid (or name) in the search box... I have tried almost all ideas posted on the net but haven't been able to figure this out..

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tiT32dpnsUMQ59ZpQdSV?p=preview) I made using your demo.

A few things to note. You'll want to include [Angular Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in your scripts and inject it into your module.

```
script(src='http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js')
```

And

```
var app = angular.module('geniuses', ["firebase","ui.bootstrap"]);
```

Also, don't use `$rootScope` to pass data around. This is a prefect use for an angular service.

There's also no need to define `ng-app` everytime you're going to use angular.

Here's the rest of the plunker code that I modified to get this working.

```
html(ng-app='geniuses')
  head
    title List All Geniuses!
    link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js')
    script(src='http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js')
    script(src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js")
    script(src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.2/angularfire.min.js")
    script(src="./app.js")

  body
    div.container
      div.page-header
       h2 All Geniuses!
        div(ng-controller='SearchAGenius')
         input.form-control(placeholder='Genius',name='search-genius',ng-model="selected",typeahead="user as user.geniusname for user in usersArr | filter:{'geniusid':$viewValue} | limitTo:8")
       div(ng-controller='GetAllGeniuses')
         ul
           li(ng-repeat='user in users') {{ user.geniusid }}
```

And the JS

```
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('geniuses', ["firebase", "ui.bootstrap"]);

  app.controller('GetAllGeniuses', ["$scope", 'GeniusFactory',
    function($scope, GeniusFactory) {

      $scope.users = GeniusFactory.users();
    }
  ]);

  app.controller('SearchAGenius', ["$scope", 'GeniusFactory',
    function($scope, GeniusFactory) {
      $scope.selected = '';
      $scope.usersArr = GeniusFactory.users();
    }
  ]);

  app.factory('GeniusFactory', ["$firebaseArray", function($firebaseArray) {
    //Create a users object
    var _users;

    return {
      users: users
    }

    function users() {
      //This will cache your users for as long as the application is running.
      if (!_users) {
        //_users = $firebaseArray(new Firebase("****"));
        _users = [{
          geniusid: "new",
          geniusname: "Harry"
        }, {
          "geniusid": "new",
          "geniusname": "Jean"
        }, {
          "geniusid": "news",
          "geniusname": "Mike"
        }, {
          "geniusid": "qazwsx",
          "geniusname": "Lynn"
        }];
      }
      console.log(_users);
      return _users;
    }
  }]);
})(angular);
```

Comment: I do have one question on this though.. The if condition in the Factory checks if _user is null or not. So, this would load only once as long as the application is running? What if new users are added ? Is there any way of forcibly refreshing this list?

Comment: You would need to write a method in the service that would allow you to push new users into the array or refresh the array from firebase. I know it's not a perfect solution but it works.

Comment: Ok.. How about injecting the array in a $global scope and then writing a watcher on it? Then, as soon as the array is modified then, write an apply function to update the contents.. If this works then could you provide me some code samples for watchers of this kind..